# Get document scores in lucene with version > 4.3?

Tags: java, lucene

Earlier you could specify to obtain scores by setting

```
searcher.setDefaultFieldSortScoring(true, true);
```

as written in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771119/lucene-how-to-get-the-score-of-a-document) answer.

Now the api suggest to use the following function,

```
public TopFieldDocs search(Query query,
                  Filter filter,
                  int n,
                  Sort sort,
                  boolean doDocScores,
                  boolean doMaxScore)
                    throws IOException
```

I simply want to get the results sorted by score, and I do not understand how to use this.
Can anyone give an example?

Comment: i think setting sort to null would achieve that... did you give it a try?

Comment: It throws the error that sort must not be null.
I am currently using Sort.RELEVANCE, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't pass in the sorting parameters, and it will sort by score, using [`IndexSearcher.search(Query, Filter, int)`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int))

You could also pass in a sort instance that sorts on relevance, using the [`Sort.RELEVANCE` constant](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html#RELEVANCE), if you prefer.  There is slightly more overhead to this than just omitting the sort, apparently, but I doubt it's all that significant.